# Return values in Prolog

Tags: math, prolog, return

I'm supposed to write a predicate that does some math stuff. But I don't know how to pass numbers or return numbers.

Maybe you can give me an example?

Let's say a predicate `divide/2` that takes two numbers `a` and `b` and returns `a/b`.

Comment: Predicates don't *Return* numbers, they *unify* variables with numbers.

Comment: http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node39.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you pass numbers in in some arguments, and you get the result back in some other argument(s) (usually last). For example

```
divide( N, D, R) :-
    R is N / D.
```

Trying:

```
112 ?- divide(100,5,X).
X = 20.
113 ?- divide(100,7,X).
X = 14.285714285714286.
```

Now, this predicate is `divide/3`, because it has *three* arguments: two for inputs and one for the output "information flow".

This is a simplified, restricted version of what a Prolog predicate can do. Which is, to not be that uni-directional.

I guess "return" is a vague term. Expression languages have expressions e-*value*-ated so a function's last expression's value becomes that function's "return" value; Prolog does *not* do that. But command-oriented languages return values by putting them into some special register. That's not much different conceptually from Prolog putting some value into some logvar.

Of course unification is more complex, and more versatile. But still, functions are relations too. Predicates "return" values by successfully unifying their arguments with them, or fail to do so, as shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64813953/849891).

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is all about unifying variables. Predicates don't return values, they just succeed or fail.

Typically when a predicate is expected to produce values based on some of the arguments then the left-most arguments are inputs and the right-most are the outputs. However, many predicates work with allowing any argument to be an input and any to be a output.

Here's an example for `multiply` showing how it is used to perform divide.

```
multiply(X,Y,Z) :- number(X),number(Y),Z is X * Y.
multiply(X,Y,Z) :- number(X),number(Z),X \= 0,Y is Z / X.
multiply(X,Y,Z) :- number(Y),number(Z),Y \= 0,X is Z / Y.
```

Now I can query it like this:

```
?- multiply(5,9,X).
X = 45 .
```

But I can easily do divide:

```
?- multiply(5,X,9).
X = 1.8 .
```

It even fails if I try to do a division by `0`:

```
?- multiply(X,0,9).
false.
```

Comment: functions are relations too. predicates "return" values by successfully unifying their arguments with them, or fail to do so. I guess "return" is a vague term. expression languages have expressions e-*value*-ated so last expression's value becomes function's "return" value; Prolog does *not* do that. but command-oriented languages return values by putting them into some special register. that's not much different conceptually from Prolog putting some value into some logvar. or course unification is more complex, and more versatile. but still. :)

Comment: your answer *does* paint this bigger, more complex picture than just saying "there's no returning values in Prolog", which is too simplistic and misleading, IMO.

Comment: The way that you use `number` to check that the arguments are numbers, you are going to mask errors. Without the checking, you will get the exception, which is arguably the right thing. Failing is really not a good idea since it will mask programming errors by putting then in the same basket as "there are no solutions".

Comment: @TA_intern *arguably*. both choices can be considered valid, each reflects different outlook. failing instead of erroring is the way of Monad, and we can't just dismiss that whole thing out of hand. it's easy to *chain* such divisions, as one thing. we can always turn possibly failing computations into lists of results easily, with findall; we can't do that with the possibly erroring computations (without resorting to extra-logical exception handling etc). some say using the *exception handling* to perform computations is what's unseemly and wrong. :)

Comment: @TA_intern in any case this Q&A is about demonstrating the very basics, without going into the finer points about it. :)

Comment: @WillNess Sure thing. I still wouldn't do it though.

Comment: @TA_intern yeah, but my intention was, does it really make this answer "not useful"?... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. So let's say you have a list [22,24,34,66] and you want to divide each answer by the number 2. First we have the base predicate where if the list is empty and the number is zero so cut. Cut means to come out of the program or just stop don't go to the further predicates. The next predicate checks each Head of the list and divides it by the number A, meaning (2). And then we simply print the Answer. In order for it to go through each element of the list we send back the Tail [24,34,66] to redo the steps. So for the next step 24 becomes the Head and the remaining digits [34,66] become the Tail.

```
divideList([],0,0):-!.
divideList([H|T],A,Answer):-
    Answer is H//A,
    writeln(Answer),
    divideList(T,A,_).

?- divideList([22,24,34,66],2,L).
OUTPUT:
11
12
17
33
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler approach:

```
divideList([],_,[]).
divideList([H|T],A,[H1|L]):-
     H1 is H//A,!,
    divideList(T,A,L).

?-divideList([22,4,56,38],2,Answer).
Answer = [11, 2, 28, 19]
```